# Inverse Laplace Transformation of an exponential function

Tags: exponential-function, laplace-transform

How one could find the inverse Laplace transformation of $\exp(-(b/(b+s))^k)$? Where both $b$ and $k$ are positive.

Comment: I tried to find its solution by using usual formula of inverse Laplace transformation but could not get any answer.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: I don't know how to do it?

Comment: Is $k$ an integer?

Comment: not necessarily, but for the moment you can consider it an integer.

Comment: Have you tried Maple or Mathematica?

Comment: Yes, I tried Mathematica 9.0, but it returns me same statement.

Answer (score 1):

For the special case $k=1$ you should have the answer

> $$ {{\rm e}^{-bt}} \left( i\sqrt {{\frac {b}{t}}}
> {\rm I_{1} \left(\,2\,\sqrt {-bt}\right)}+\delta \left( t \right) \right) ,$$

where $I_n(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and $\delta(x)$ is the dirac delta function.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to compute 
$$
\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}e^{xs-\left(\tfrac{b}{b+s}\right)^k}ds=e^{-bx}
\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}e^{x(b+s)-\left(\tfrac{b}{b+s}\right)^k}ds.
$$
For $x$ positive and $k$ positive integer this is equal to
$$
e^{-bx}\operatorname{res}_{z=0}e^{xz-\left(\tfrac{b}{z}\right)^k}.
$$
The residue is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent series:
$$
\operatorname{res}_{z=0}e^{xz-\left(\tfrac{b}{z}\right)^k}=\sum_{n-kl=1}\frac{x^n}{n!}\frac{(-b)^{kl}}{l!}=x\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{(-bx)^{kl}}{l!(kl+1)!}
$$
Now Mathematica says that
$$
\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{y^{l}}{l!(kl+1)!}={}_0F_k\left(;\frac2k,\frac3k,\dots,\frac{k+1}k;\frac{y}{k^k}\right),
$$
and it remains to subsitute $y=(-bx)^k$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to t}\left\{e^{-\left(\frac{b}{b+s}\right)^k}\right\}$

$=\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to t}\left\{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nb^{kn}}{n!(b+s)^{kn}}\right\}$

$=\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to t}\left\{1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nb^{kn}}{n!(b+s)^{kn}}\right\}$

$=\delta(t)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nb^{kn}t^{kn-1}e^{-bt}}{n!\Gamma(kn)}$